# Power Query / M - Can I control order of operations to support two OR options

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm trying to conditionally replace a column if both of these columns are either null or had blank space. I would like to know if this is possible for future use of this logic with other conditions. I don't know how to force the two OR statements simultaneously as parenthesis would in a math function or SQL.

Psuedo code

- replace `column a` with `not listed`,

  - if `column a is null or blank` and `column b is null or blank`.

I was trying the following, but it made everything that had a null `[NOT LISTED]`.

I'm' looking for IF (column a is X OR Y) AND (column b is X OR Y) then replace column a with [NOT LISTED]
Parenthesis in this language are for functions unlike SQL. Is there some character that is the equivalent or way to force the order of operations?

```
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Previous step",
  each [Country],
  each if [Country"] = null or Text.Trim([Country]) = "" and 
         [#"Org Country"] = null or Text.Trim([#"Org Country"]) = ""
     then "[NOT LISTED]"
         else null

   Replacer.ReplaceValue,
   {"Country"}
)
```

Comment: Where did you find information that in `M` parentheses could not be used for grouping logicals? As far as I can tell, parentheses can be used in `M` formuals to control the order of calculation.

Comment: I guess I had bad placement with the each and the parenthesis or something before and it was asking me for a function. @RonRosenfeld you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
x=  Table.ReplaceValue(#"PriorStepNameHere",  each [a],  each if ([a]=null or [a]="") and ([b]=null or [b]="")  then "Not Listed" else [a] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"a"})
```

[image]

if **a** and **b** are blank or null, make **a** into "not listed" otherwise leave **a** alone